# bash: =: No such file or directory .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash

Every time I open terminal it says:

```
bash: =: No such file or directory
```

What would cause this?

Comment: Do you have a custom `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`, or did you install something new right before this started happening?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your question and add the content of each your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` using the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You probably have space between variable name and = sign. Please remember that variable assignment in `bash` must be without spaces, like `var="variable value can have spaces, but assignment cannot"`

Comment: Yes, i edited ~/.bashrc file and install some software on my ubuntu before this happen

Comment: Well then just show us what you did and we'll tell you what's wrong. However, chances are [Sergiy the visionary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977486/bash-no-such-file-or-directory#comment1569388_977486) already got it right… ;)

Comment: I did not know this happened because of my .bashrc file. So i am sorry if my answer was not correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I edited my `.bashrc file and added a source variable:

```
source = /etc/environment
```

Variable assignment in bash must be without spaces. Editing it to:

```
source=/etc/environment
```

solved the problem

Comment: I am curious about why you wanted to assign this variable, because sometimes we want to `source /etc/environment`... If you feel like explaining further, please do. In any case, well done for fixing your problem

Answer (score 3):

The error that you see has two main reasons for existence.

1. You have spaces between variable name and variable assignment. Proper sytax is to have `variable="some value"`
2. Your variable is named `source`. `source` is actually a [shell built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) command. Exactly because you had space between `source` and `=` the first word in the line was considered a command by the shell.

   ```
   $ bash -c 'source = "something"'
   bash: =: No such file or directory
   ```

   Because `source` is `bash` built-in command , you see `bash` mentioned in the error. Compare this for example with another command:

   ```
   $ bash -c 'stat = "something"'                                                                                                                                   
   stat: cannot stat '=': No such file or directory
   stat: cannot stat 'something': No such file or directory
   ```

   Please note that the core of the issue is that *line is interpreted as command with positional parameters given*. It doesn't mean that variable name is incorrect and in fact you could use those variable names ( even though I'd say it's a poor practice to use names of variables similar to existing command names, but that's just my opinion):

   ```
   $ bash -c 'stat="something";echo "$stat"'
   something

   $ bash -c 'source="something";echo "$source"'                                                                                                                       
   something
   ```